# Wordpress; How use jQuery plugin in the header?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

The error i receive: uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'sticky'

I'm transferring a website, I've made into Wordpress. The site is using a sticky header plugin. Situation is that the jquery handler doesn't work. I've tryed no-conflict and placing the code in a file named function.php. Could anyone pinpoint some good methods? it seems a little unnecassary to put that less code in a seperated file.

many thanks in advance :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('HTML_type');?>" charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<title>
<?php wp_title('Het blinde konijn', true, 'rights'); ?>
<?php bloginfo('name');?>
</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<?php
    wp_deregister_script('jquery'); 
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js', false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); 
?>
<?php wp_enqueue_script('stickyheader', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-sticky.js', array('jquery')); ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function(){
    $j("#header").sticky({topSpacing:0});
    resizeWindow();
    $j(window).bind("resize", resizeWindow);
        function resizeWindow(e) {
            contentHeight = $j(window).height() - $j("#header").height();
            $j(".zebra li").css("max-height", contentHeight);
        }
});
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Can you post a link to the website? It'll make it easier to find the problem.

Comment: wherer did you include the above code. Did you try header.php file in theme folder?

Comment: So, this is your `header.php` file or not? It should be. Also, is that a custom theme. Most themes nowadays use HTML5 - as they should imo.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems good.

Have you tried to check is Jquery is correctly imported in your page with the script registering?
Which version of Jquery are you using? Last (2.0) or 1.9 ?

Some plugins don't work with 2.0; you may try to import 1.9 instead of 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

`wp_deregister_script('jquery'); 
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js', false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');` belongs to functions.php.

Define following class (of course you could rename it):

```
.sticky {  
        position: fixed;  
        width: 100%;  
        left: 0;  
        top: 0;  
        z-index: 100;  
        border-top: 0;  
    }
```

Change your script to the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  var stickyNavTop = $('.nav').offset().top;  

  var stickyNav = function(){  
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();  

    if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) {   
      $('.nav').addClass('sticky');  
    } else {  
      $('.nav').removeClass('sticky');   
    }  
  };  

  stickyNav();  

  $(window).scroll(function() {  
    stickyNav();  
  });  
});
```

While .nav is your sticky element.

You could use a jQuery-Plugin like "[Sticky Plugin](http://stickyjs.com/)" as well.

Comment: That was a worthless comment not near what  I was asking

Comment: Hmm, i see. I did overread that. Still morning over here. Sorry for stealing your time! ^^

Comment: Hope i could get myself out of misery like that. ;-)

Comment: Do you mind telling me what went wrong with my solution or either vote it up? =)